# Power analysis in R - Sample size

Tags: r, statistical-power

I have a question regarding power analysis in R using the following function:

```
library(pwr2)
pwr.2way(a=2, b=8, alpha=0.01, size.A=12, size.B=12, f.A=0.47, f.B=0.4)
```

whereas:

```
a=levels of first group
b=levels of second group
alpha=confidence interval
sizeA=sample size of group A
sizeB= sample size of groupB
f.A=effect size of A
f.B=effect size of B
```

I'm wondering if my sizeA and sizeB is correct and why there are two variables for it. I'm working with a two way anova in a full factorial design.

Isn't the sample size always the same for both group A and group B?

Are there cases where the sample size differs?

Like I said, I'm using a 2x8 full factorial design with a repetition of 12 per treatment. So did I use the right sample size in my code above?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for us to know if what you did is correct -- that depends on your situation. But there are certainly cases where the sample size varies two groups (or more than two groups). In observational studies, I'd say it's usually the case that the sample sizes vary.